# Prove that $P(x)$ is a polynomial.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $P(x)\in C^\infty(a,b)$, if $\forall x\in(a,b)$, there exist some $n_x\in N^*$, such that $P^{(n_x)}(x)=0$. Can you prove that $P(x)$ is a polynomial?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial

Comment: This is often called the theorem or Corominas and Suñer y Balaguer.

Comment: Great question, even if known.  I had never seen this before.

Comment: See this [question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial) in MO.